# lightning-datatable row number error

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a lightning web component, using lighting-datatable with row-numbers visible. This works well up to 99 records... then I get this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My component code:

```
        <lightning-datatable
            key-field="id"
            data={responses}
            columns={columns}
            onsort={handleSort}
            sorted-by={sortedBy}
            sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
            enable-infinite-loading
            onloadmore={handleLoadMore}>
        </lightning-datatable>
```

Is the row numbering limited, am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug? Any workarounds?

Comment: Please add the part that's an answer as an answer. You're allowed to answer your own questions here.

Comment: Got it. I was thinking I had to wait before I could answer my own question... but I see the delay is just in accepting it.

Comment: yep. You're absolutely right. You've got my +1.

Answer (score 5):

Just figured it out myself. I didn't have show-row-number-column in the html. Now it works fine. But, that brings up a different question... what if I didn't want to show row numbers. The docs suggest that I would just leave show-row-number-column out of the markup and then they won't show. But I didn't have it in the markup before and they displayed.

[image]

Updated markup:

```
<lightning-datatable
    key-field="id"
    data={responses}
    columns={columns}
    onsort={handleSort}
    sorted-by={sortedBy}
    sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
    onrowaction={handleRowAction}
    show-row-number-column
    enable-infinite-loading
    onloadmore={handleLoadMore}>
</lightning-datatable>
```

BTW, there's a lot [more info in the dev guide here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_datatable_inline_edit) that isn't detailed in the reference materials. In particular, how to handle draftValues, which is necessary to get the Cancel/Save buttons to disappear after an inline edit.

Comment: This is a bug in the component I just discovered too! I do not want to show the row numbers and apparently there is no way to hide them other that custom CSS which I am not sure will work because one of the nuances about LWC is the components exist in the ShadowDom and CSS won't cascade from parent to child.

Comment: I'm facing a similar on the aura version, showRowNumberColumn paramater doesn't work at all. Is there a workaround for this? @PatMcClellan__c

Comment: Rows numbers are displayed if you have any columns in editable mode. It is mentioned in the docs. We can't hide them.

Comment: link in the answer is broken. Updated: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_table_inline_edit